# Django application switcher in Django Admin

Tags: python, django

I have a `Django Project` with 3 applications in it. `app1, app2, app3`
I want to create an interface that allow admin to activate any application.

- Admin can change the current (active) application from admin interface.

### Idea

1. Create a Model with 3 Choices as applications
2. Allow admin to choose from the application.

This is what i think; but what are the other things which change accordingly?

### Option

Where the check would make more sense? `urls.py` or `INSTALLED_APPS`?
How check and manage the currently activate application effectively?

Can anyone suggest me some approach?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just remove the app from the `INSTALLED_APPS` because your project `urls.py` has reference to the app's urls.  So you have to somehow handle the task at url level.

I think that simplest solution is to create a middleware which will catch urls for disabled apps and raise 404 error:

**models.py**

```
class BlockedUrl(models.Model):

    url_to_block = models.CharField(max_length=100,
                                    help_text='For exaple: /polls/')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.url_to_block
```

**admin.py**

```
class BlockedUrlAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(BlockedUrl, BlockedUrlAdmin)
```

**settings.py**

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
    'app.middleware.BlockedUrlsMiddeware',
)
```

**app/middleware.py**

```
from django.http import Http404    
from app.models import BlockedUrl

class BlockedUrlsMiddeware(object):

    def process_request(self, request):
        for url in BlockedUrl.objects.values_list('url_to_block', flat=True):
            if request.path.startswith(url):
                raise Http404
```

Now admin can add any url to the list of blocked urls (but don't try to add `/admin/` to this list :-)

Of course this is just the proof of concept and your logic may be different.

Comment: that would be so hectic for the admin to add every new url that does not belong to the particular application. 
I am looking that if i change the value in the model (select one application) and after saving; my server gets restart. Why? when the server will restart; it will load the new value from the model and set it in the settings.py.